# Call FindExecutable in Java

Tags: java, windows, winapi

I need to find out which default windows program is executed when opening a text (.txt) file. For this purpose I want to call the [FindExecutable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from windows.

How can this be achieved from Java?

I hope I do not have to make a JNI-implementation to call Windows via C for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use JNI.  If you don't to code it yourself, you can use [JNA](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/overview-summary.html) - I believe that JNA has moved to GitHub, but the documentation at the previous link is the best I could find.  Note that you *will* be using JNI no matter what (and deploying a native dll), but JNA does make it a lot easier.